# DataApi data not found (not display in Html) in Ionic2

Tags: json, api, ionic2, ngfor

I'm developing an application for Ionic 2.I'm taking pictures from JSON, and I list the data in the console.log.However they're not displayed in HTML.Error (GET http://ukopuz.com/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) )Where did I go wrong?

**data-api.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';


 @Injectable()
 export class DataApi {


 private url = 'http://ukopuz.com/api/2'; 

 constructor(private http:Http){
 }

  getReferenceData(){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
     this.http.get(`${this.url}`) 
    .subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()))
  });
 }

}
```

**reference.html**

```
  <ion-content class="content">

    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let ref of reference">
         <ion-col col-4 >
           <img src="http://ukopuz.com/{{ref}}" >
         </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

**reference.ts**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ModalController } from 
'ionic-angular';
 import {DataApi} from '../../app/dataapi/data-api.service';
 import {Http, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
 import {ModalPage} from '../modal/modal';

 @IonicPage()
 @Component({
  selector: 'page-references',
  templateUrl: 'references.html',
  })
  export class ReferencesPage {

  reference : any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
  NavParams,public dataApi:DataApi,
   public http:HttpModule,public modalCtrl:ModalController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
   console.log('ionViewDidLoad ReferencesPage');
    this.dataApi.getReferenceData().then(data =>
     this.reference = data);
      console.log("data:"+ this.reference );
     console.log("viewload");
}


 }
```

**data.json**

```
[
 {
   "3": "/img/ref/adana.png",
   "4": "/img/ref/ajans.png",
   "5": "/img/ref/akp.jpg",
   "6": "/img/ref/akp.png",
   "7": "/img/ref/akpgenclik.png",
   "8": "/img/ref/ankara.png",
   "9": "/img/ref/arnavut.png",
   "10": "/img/ref/aydin.png"
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Try with `<img [src]="'http://ukopuz.com/' + ref" >`. Notice the [ and ] in the src attribute.

Comment: unfortunately, not working   error(GET http://ukopuz.com/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found))

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your return json from API, it is not returning any data due to this you are getting any response in your .html page

Check the API page

Comment: Thank you for your interest.I am using api Ionic1 without any problems.The data is displayed.I have a problem with Ionic2.